# Disable Chome's swipe navigation features with HTML, CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

With Chrome you can swipe right on a trackpad or a Magic Mouse and navigate back in your browser history. Is there any way to disable this without messing with browser flags? Can we, for instance make our website a Chrome app that has this feature disabled, can we write a Chrome plugin or can we do some tricky JavaScript to help us out?

Comment: Help you out with _what exactly_? If you want to change how the browser UI that the user is accustomed to behaves, you should have a really good reason to do so.

Comment: I really do, i work as a front end dev at a german newspaper and this is a internal web-based app only used by journalists—under high pressure—and this browser feature leads to critical unwanted behavior

Comment: How to do it via flags: http://askubuntu.com/questions/800188/disabling-chrome-swipe-navigation-two-finger-back Not sure if there’s any way to disable it via script or so though; it _is_ a user setting after all.

Comment: How about an handling the `beforeunload` event instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload